# Play Framework 2 doesn't compile on runtime

Tags: compilation, playframework-2.0

I am running Play 2.2.1 on my MacOSx Mavericks and it doesn't detect any alterations on any file when I modify them. On Windows it always recompiles the project when it detects alterations while doing a browser request.
On Mac for the alterations to be compiled I need to end Play's server process and do a "**play run**" or "**play ~run**" again.

Does anyone know what can I do to make this work?

edit: Disabling "Build automatically" on Eclipse doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On Mac it also always recompile, I can ensure you ... Sorry have no idea

Comment: My friend got the same problem months ago and the only solution was to develop on a Windows machine

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse, it might keep your project loaded in memory before the actual writing  to the disk. Meanwhile, Play only check the filesystem, not Eclipse's cache.

You can confirm this behaviour by starting the Play project and then try to update one of the files in a basic editor such as Sublime Text or even vim.

Comment: I tried that, without success. I don't understand. Works great on windows though.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen other people report this issue and the general fix (which you've tried) seems to be to turn off the "Build Automatically" option in your Eclipse project. Some people have said that they needed to restart their machine after turning off that option to actually see any change.

There's also [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/5k3zzQaeXII/xy5WE8gjhm4J) on the play-framework Google group and this is the last post:

> For the benefit of anyone running into this issue still or googling for it. On OSX (maybe only some versions?), the way the folder was created (command line vs finder) or the case used in the parent paths seems to trigger the issue.
>
> We've been able to resolve it by moving the project to a new path (all lower case after the home dir) or by recreating all the paths in finder. I am not sure which one resolved it, but one of them did. After that, hot-reloading works fine.
>
> Alvaro